# Timestamp to Date in jQuery

Tags: jquery, timestamp

I'm new with jQuery and i need some help with a basic issue.

I tried to convert `timestamp` value to `date`

```
MyDate = new Date(value);
```

Here is the output:

```
Wed Jan 28 2015 16:26:07 GMT+0200 (IST)
```

And i want the output to be:

```
28/01/2015 16:26:07
```

Can someone show me how to do that? Unfortunately, and didn't manage to find it in the web. Probably since i'm not experienced enough.

Comment: Handling date formatting in JS is a nightmare. I would strongly suggest the use of a plugin such as [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) or [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toISOString();
```

This will give the following output:

```
2015-01-29T14:27:19.714Z
```

If you care to write more code, try using the following methods:

```
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth();
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
```

You have the values in the variables and now can display them in whatever format you want. Similar methods exist for time as well.

For still better handling of dates, consider using Date.js.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch each part separatly and write out the desired output like this:

```
function format_date(date) {
  month=date.getMonth();
  month=month+1; //javascript date goes from 0 to 11
  if (month<10) month="0"+month; //adding the prefix

  year=date.getFullYear();
  day=date.getDate();
  hour=date.getHours();
  minutes=date.getMinutes();
  seconds=date.getSeconds();

  return day+"/"+month+"/"+year+" "+hour+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;

}

MyDate = new Date(value);
formatedDate=format_date(MyDate);
```